# Why sort() function cannot be applied to list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> a = [i for i in range(3,0,-1)]
>>> a
[3, 2, 1]
>>> b = [i for i in range(3,0,-1)].sort()
>>> b
>>> c = sorted(i for i in range(3,0,-1))
>>> c
[1, 2, 3]
```

The b becomes None, which does not make sense.

Comment: You can't directly apply the sort method over the list.

Comment: `.sort` is a in-place method for `list` objects, use `sorted` the built-in function to sort arbitrary iterables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sort()` method operates in-place and returns `None`. You must first store the list, then call sort on it. For b, you first create the list, then sort it, with the return value of `sort()` being assigned to b, and the original list being lost.